# Instructions Page

Tags: android

I have just finished my first app in Android and now I want to build a small instructions page that will open when the application opens. Id like the user to be able to read a small set instructions and then just click a close button on the same screen to close the screen and begin using the application.

Should I do the with an alert box or is there a better way?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would recommend against doing this.  The first time a user opens your app, this is fine and makes sense (though if your app has an intuitive interface it could be unnecessary even then) but what about the 2nd time?  The 22nd time?

Comment: @Ichorus: I agree with your concerns but as long as you use a 'first run' approach then it will never happen again. I use `SharedPreferences` to store a boolean called `firstRun` which allows my app to know if it's the first time the user has used it after installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an `Activity` with the `style` set as `Theme.Dialog` you do this in the AndroidManifest.xml as follows...

```
<activity
    android:name=".InstructionsActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

    ...

</activity>
```

Use `SharedPreferences` to save a 'first run' boolean and check it in the `onCreate(...)` method of your MAIN/LAUNCHER Activity - if the boolean is `true` then set it to `false` then use `startActivity(...)` to start your `InstructionsActivity` dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a small activity with a `TextView` of your instructional information in a `ScrollView` with an anchored Close button at the bottom of the page.

Consider a layout similar to the Android first-setup layout:

[image: Android setup page]

You would use a centered Close button instead of a next button, but the idea would be the same. This is a very clean layout for longer messages in an application.

Comment: This is exactly what Im looking for but I dont have the first clue how to start a separate activity before my app runs. Can anyone give me a research direction to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

The `AlertDialog` is good for this however longer content may be better with a mobile optimized web page and don't forget to make the help available from other parts of the application.